# iptables forward port from IP address to an IP address on another PC

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to achieve exactly the same solution as the answer in this post (which works locally):

[How to forward connection from one interface to another under linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/125625/how-to-forward-connection-from-one-interface-to-another-under-linux)

Except I need to forward to an IP address on another machine.

What do I need to do to get it to forward to an IP on another machine?

Eg: Machine A has 192.168.0.6
Machine B has 10.0.0.2

On the gateway if a client accesses 192.168.0.6 port 443 I want to forward it to the other PC at 10.0.0.2

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1286555/iptables-port-forwarding-with-internal-snat

Hope it helps someone else.